# Combining multiple records from different tables into one string

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to use a studentID to get their first and surname from one table, then get the results for one of their Homeworks using a HomeworkID, and have the results displayed in a listbox widget using tkinter. However before it can be displayed ofcourse I first need to be able to get the data.
This what I have so far:

```
 def viewresults (self, sethw):

        print (self.Homework_To_Set.get())
        #resultslist = []
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        homeworkID = c.execute("SELECT HWID FROM HomeworkInfo WHERE HomeworkName = ?", (self.Homework_To_Set.get(), )).fetchone()
        studentsnamecheck = c.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM HomeworkSet WHERE  HWID = ?", ((homeworkID[0], ))).fetchall()
        if len(studentsnamecheck) == 0:
            self.View_Results.insert(END, "No one has completed this homework!")
        else:
            for x in studentsnamecheck:
                c.execute("SELECT FName || ' ' || SName FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (str(x), ))
                res1 = (c.fetchall())
                for i in (studentsnamecheck):
                    result_collect = c.execute("SELECT Results FROM HomeworkSet WHERE StudentID = ? AND HWID = ?", ((str(i)), self.Homework_To_Set.get() ))

                var_insert_results = ((res1), (result_collect))
                self.View_Results.insert(END, str(var_insert_results))
```

And this is the current output:

```
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
([], <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001F40E1809D0>)
```

This is the schema for the databases:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            FName text,
            SName text,
            username text,
            password text,
            userType text,
            ClassName text);""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClassInfo (
            ClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            ClassName text,
            Teacher text);""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkInfo (
            HWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            HomeworkName text);""")


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkSet (
            HWID integer,
            StudentID text,
            Results text,
            FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES users(UserID)
            FOREIGN KEY (HWID) REFERENCES HomeworkInfo(HWID));""")
```

Comment: ***"current output: ... <sqlite3.Cursor object" ...***: You have to loop the resulting `.Cursor object` again

Comment: You can use SQL JOIN to combine the three SELECT statements, and so you can use one for loop to go through the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

```
c.execute("SELECT FName || ' ' || SName FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (str(x), ))
res1 = (c.fetchall())
for i in (studentsnamecheck):
    result_collect = c.execute("SELECT Results FROM HomeworkSet WHERE StudentID = ? AND HWID = ?",
                               ((str(i)), self.Homework_To_Set.get() ))
```

- No `UserID` field in `users` table; it may be `username`
- `str(x)` should be `x[0]`
- should loop through `res1` instead of `studentsnamecheck`
- `str(i)` should be `x[0]`
- `self.Homework_To_Set.get()` should be `homeworkID[0]`

So the code should be:

```
def viewresults(self, sethw):
    print(self.Homework_To_Set.get())
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    homeworkID = c.execute("SELECT HWID FROM HomeworkInfo WHERE HomeworkName = ?",
                           (self.Homework_To_Set.get(),)).fetchone()
    studentsnamecheck = c.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM HomeworkSet WHERE HWID = ?",
                                  (homeworkID[0],)).fetchall()
    if len(studentsnamecheck) == 0:
        self.View_Results.insert(END, "No one has completed this homework!")
    else:
        for x in studentsnamecheck:
            c.execute("SELECT FName||' '||SName FROM users WHERE username = ?", (x[0],))
            res1 = c.fetchall()
            for i in res1:
                results = c.execute("SELECT Results FROM HomeworkSet WHERE StudentID = ? AND HWID = ?",
                                    (x[0], homeworkID[0])).fetchone()
                self.View_Results.insert(END, '%-30s  %s'%(i[0], results[0]))
```

However, you can combine the `SELECT` statements into one query:

```
def viewresults(self, sethw):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = """
        SELECT SName||' '||FName, Results
        FROM HomeworkSet, HomeworkInfo, users
        WHERE HomeworkInfo.HomeworkName = ?
          AND HomeworkInfo.HWID = HomeworkSet.HWID
          AND HomeworkSet.StudentID = users.username
    """
    c.execute(sql, (self.Homework_To_Set.get(),))
    for result in c:
        self.View_Results.insert(END, '%-30s  %s'%result)
```